# Reference Code for Positive Basis Pursuit Denoising

Tags: matlab, optimization, compressive-sensing

I am trying to reconstruct a positive sparse signal using compressed sensing (friedlanders code), I cannot find a way to impose the positivity constraint for this implementation. I have seen some papers discussing positive signals case but cannot find any code implementations, can anyone please point out to any relevant code.

Comment: Does it matter which programming language? Python, Matlab, etc.?

Comment: nope, anything is fine

Comment: @Pavan, Could you mark my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SparseLab should be able to solve the positivity-constrained problem: [SparseLab (Stanford) - Seeking Sparse Solutions to Linear System of Equations](http://sparselab.stanford.edu/).

See [Donoho & Tanner, "Precise Undersampling Theorems"](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/tanner/papers/DoTa_PUT.pdf) for a definition of the problem.

This toolbox depends on Matlab.

Comment: thank you very much, this is what I was looking for, esp. the non-negative fourier example

Comment: @Pavan you're welcome. Consider voting the answer up.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're after the following optimization problem:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \; & {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} \\
\text{subject to} \; & A x = b \\
& x \succeq 0
\end{align*}$$

This is pretty simple problem if we pay attention fo the fast that given $ x \succeq 0 $ then $ {\left\| x \right\|}_{1} = \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x $.

This means the above problem is equivalent of:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \; & \boldsymbol{1}^{T} x \\
\text{subject to} \; & A x = b \\
& x \succeq 0
\end{align*}$$

Now, this is a [Linear Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) problem which can be easily solved using MATLAB or any other LP solver.

For instance, in MATLAB it will be something like that:

```
numRows = 10;
numCols = 100;

mA = randn([numRows, numCols]);
vB = randn([numRows, 1]);

vE = ones([numCols, 1]); %<! Vector of ones to sum vX

vX = linprog(vE, [], [], mA, vB, zeros([numCols, 1]), inf([numCols, 1]));
```